# Get list of AD groups a user is a member of

Tags: windows, active-directory

Suppose I have the user id of a user in Active Directory.  I'd like to get a list of all AD groups in which that user is currently a member of.  How can I do this from the Windows command line?

I've tried the following:

```
dsget user "DC=jxd123" -memberof
```

**Error:**

```
dsquery failed:'-memberof' is an unknown parameter.
type dsquery /? for help.
```

Comment: You certainly won't get an error for dsquery when you execute dsget. Copy&Paste fail?

Comment: FYI, found the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5072996/190298) on StackOverflow with a couple more answers.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer, but assuming you are using powershell, you can write this: Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072996/how-to-get-all-groups-that-a-user-is-a-member-of

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do this in PowerShell pretty easily. I'm sure you can do it with the ds tools too, but they're old and crusty and PowerShell should be used for everything possible nowadays.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
(Get-ADUser userName –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
```

Shorter version

```
(Get-ADUser userName –Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
```

Comment: I downloaded Powershell, and now have a *.msu file.  How do I install it using the *.msu file?

Comment: What operating system are you on? PowerShell is built into anything newer than XP and is available to XP as an optional Windows Update.

Comment: Windows XP .. My company is slow :-\

Comment: Then you downloaded the wrong installer. Also, just a heads up, XP support ends in just under a year. Get upgrades moving! http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/endofsupport.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I work for a hospital, so we have hundreds of thousands of workstations.  They are upgrading to Windows 7 next April.  I don't have any control over hot fixes unfortunately.  It's done via some Novell scripts.  I just work in research.

Comment: `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` is another way to do this in PowerShell.

Comment: I get only a error: `FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand`. But the other PowerShell one-liner from @Canoas does work very well!

Comment: find this link for updated powershell command https://akshaya-m.blogspot.com/2018/04/powershell-find-user-exist-in-ad-group.html

Comment: I get this error:
Import-Module : The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.

Answer (score 115):

Or with the *net user* command...

```
net user /domain username
```

Comment: I love the simplicity that some of the "old" DOS commands offer.  And, they've always been there so even if you don't have PoSH loaded on an old machine, DOS comes to the rescue!  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: This will only return explicit, but not implicit group memberships.

Comment: Slick command, BUT, the groups names in the output are truncated to 21 characters... :-(

Comment: Yes, there are limitations. Nested group memberships are not shown and you are right, the output is truncated. Admittedly, I had not considered the latter.

Comment: Worked great but why would it be truncated? Is there a config/parameter that can be added for full group name?

Comment: This one is nice since it comes out of the box with Windows so will work on client machines joined to the domain which may not have AD Powershell cmdlets installed

Answer (score 72):

Single line, no modules necessary, uses current logged user $($env:username), runs from other windows machines:

```
(New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$($env:username)))")).FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().memberOf
```

Qudos to this vbs/powershell article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730963.aspx

Comment: Very good solution, the only one which worked for me without installing any additional softwar! Thanks!

Comment: +1 for working on a restricted system without any additional software!

Comment: Another +1 here for both working on a restricted system and having better output than net.exe. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is just **perfect solution** indeed. It gets **non-truncated** group names and works with limited permissions. For quick ad hoc view I use `net group <name> /domain`. But when full group names are critical this PS snippet is a life-saver.

Comment: Perfect Solution

Comment: Any comment on how to make this work for other usernames than the one logged in? Apparently it returns blank when I search for a different user...

Answer (score 24):

If you need to see your own groups, there's [`whoami /groups`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299.aspx):

> Displays the user groups to which the current user belongs.

The advantage of this command over `net user /domain username` is that implicit group memberships are also displayed with `whoami`.

Comment: Best solution. Upvoted. Short and sweet. Doesn't truncate. Personally I like best the LIST format, i.e. `whoami /groups /fo list`, because it is the easiest to read with the eye.

Comment: Best answer here especially on corporate systems where utilities are severely limitied.

Comment: Only works for current use though

Comment: @peterh The default format is better when you search for something, as in `whoami /groups | findstr LICENSE`

Answer (score 12):

**Found a good resource:**

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2195.active-directory-dsquery-commands.aspx

**Here's how to do it from Windows command prompt:**

```
dsquery user -samid jxd123 | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid
```

Answer (score 12):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity jdoe | Format-Table -Property name
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach: a PowerShell script that lists all implicit group memberships from the Windows account token. Works on a restricted system.

```
$token = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() 
ForEach($group in $token.Groups){
    $group.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dsquery user -samid "user id" | dsget user -memberof > userid_memberof.txt
```

Comment: Add the `-expand` parameter to include indirect group memberships

Answer (score 2):

adfind is another great tool for this sort of thing.  It is a free tool from MVP Joe Richards

http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/

You can use one of the shortucts

```
adfind -sc u:username memberof
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ADUser = Read-Host "Provide the AD User account"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ADUser | Sort-Object name | Format-Table -Expand name
```

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell version returns just the AD group names, rather than the DN of the group. The 'select-object' output can easily be piped to a CSV or test file.

`(Get-ADUser ExampleUser –Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name`

Answer (score 0):

Powershell, gives a nice and clean output.

```
(get-aduser USER -Properties MemberOf | select MemberOf).MemberOf | % {$_.split(",")[0].replace("CN=","")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gpresult -V /user blah
```

Comment: I use gpresult and find it simple and effective. I don't know why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution searching all domains under the given domain (assuming proper permission for each domain):

```
# provide the logon name here:
$user="alice"
$allGroups=@()

foreach ( $d in (Get-ADForest example.net).domains ) { Write-Output "Looking up $user in domain $d"; $allGroups += Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user -ResourceContextServer $d }

$allGroups | ft name,GroupScope,distinguishedName -AutoSize
```

Using [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617259.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Try adquery (if you're on Linux/RHEL)

#To find All AD groups a user "XXXX" is a part of:

```
adquery user -a XXXX
```

Conversely, to find all users an Active Directory group "ABCD" has:

```
adquery group -a ABCD
```

You can pipe with grep to refine further.

These commands can be run when you are logged on as a standard user without elevated privileges.

For windows operating system, [Jack](https://serverfault.com/a/532110/454582)'s answer is relevant.

More info here: https://docs.centrify.com/Content/auth-unix-user/CommandLineUsers.htm