# Get list of AD groups a user is a primary owner of

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-permissions

i would like to get list of AD groups a user is a primary owner of.
i have gone through [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/532106/get-list-of-ad-groups-a-user-is-a-member-of?newreg=cdc305f9e5ef4f2e950c9e47068e1d73) question already.  But its not giving me the attribute/property whether the user is a primary owner of secondary owner.

How to get the above requirement. the below code is for getting the memberonly. ( Please correct me , if i am wrong)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
(Get-ADUser userName –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
```

Comment: Primary owner; I am unfamiliar with this term?  Do you mean direct member?  If so, then you what you have above is correct.

Comment: @semicolon  do we have a property / attribute name called "Primary Owner"  or ""Secondary Owner" , so that we can easily get user's Groups having him as the "Group Owner "

Comment: A user has a primary group; a group can have a manager (which may or may not be able to update membership).  But - unless you have custom attributes- there is nothing named primary/secondary owner.  What are you looking for?  Are you sure you’re not referring to direct membership ( user is in group)  and indirect/nested membership ( a user is in a group that is then a member of a separate group)?

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADGroup -Filter 'managedby -eq ""'

Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(managedby=)'